# How do I install PHP engine on Windows 8.1?

Tags: php, mysql

It says up above: "Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more."  So here goes....

I run Win8.1.  I've been learning PHP and mySQL and for that reason I installed WAMP server, Zend Server, Zend Studio and phpMyAdmin.  Zend Studio was on a 30 day trial and it's now expired, but right now I can't afford to buy a licence.

I've been researching an alternative to Zend Studio and I came across the PHP Engine via the wikihow site (http://www.wikihow.com/Install-the-PHP-Engine-on-Your-Windows-PC), so I went to php.net and downloaded the PHP binaries.  But there's no installer that I can see and though I downloaded the binaries I haven't been able to install the engine.

So, my questions are:

1. Am I on the right track to be able to run PHP with mySQL, given that I have Apache downloaded via the WAMP server?
2. If not, what else can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions to edit your past questions?

Comment: Just download and install Xampp.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Xampp server which is very easy to install and configure, download: http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/ and here is the tutorial link: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/articles/run-a-php-program-in-xampp-server

Answer (score 0):

this is microsoft recommended step on windows

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2819022

Comment: Thanks Anfas.  I have downloaded IIS and PHP, but I can't see how to develop and run PHP scripts.

Comment: check out the website there is step by step instruction

Comment: thanks again Anfas.  I have Eclipse installed and linked to the php.exe, but when I execute a php file as php cli, I do not get any output in the browser view.  Any thoughts?

Comment: It seems from testing that pure php produces output, but that html and javascript are not recognised. Do thay have to be linked too?  I was used to Zend Studio where all this was included.